# Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

Trying to open a file i might get a error code 32 (sharing violation).

How can i figure out which process (e.g. process ID, or thread id) that is locking the file?

### Bonus Reading

- Superuser: [Find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/117902/8169)
- Technet: [How to find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20190430125147/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-find-out-which-c0d4e60e)
- Technet: [How to find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows by PowerShell](https://web.archive.org/web/20190430125147/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-find-out-which-c0d4e60e)
- Technet: [How to find out which process is locking a file or folder in Windows by VBScript](https://web.archive.org/web/20200319093310/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-find-out-which-6012b2ac)
- [Windows: files locked by process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47476625/12597)
- [Winapi: Get the process which has specific handle of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47507578/12597)
- [How to check if a file is being used by another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31137840/12597) *(which asks a different question: How to check if a file is in use by another application. I already know it is in use by another application (hence the sharing violation). I need to know **who** is using it.)*

Comment: are you look for  https://stackoverflow.com/a/47510579/6401656 ?

Comment: [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) can show you which handles are open by which processes

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, but in concrete case better use *FileProcessIdsUsingFileInformation* information for file. this is exactly show information for this concrete file

Comment: Or using the Restart Manager. This is good: [How do I find out which process is locking a file using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623311/7444103) -- Mentioned and demonstrated in: [How do I find out which process has a file open?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=8283)

Comment: In all these cases, since this is a programming web-site, i need the *code* that can do it - not a tool.